# Downloading and immediately uploading: is there a system to download files to a fast cache rather than all the way to my desktop

Tags: download

I regularly download files from one bit of the internet only to upload them somewhere else (just now it was a video file).  In such circumstances I very very rarely touch the file locally.

It would be a lot quicker for me if instead of downloading all the way to my desktop I could have the file download to some server with a fast connection, and then use that server to upload it again elsewhere, thus meaning the file never arrives on my desktop and the whole process is much faster.

EDIT - so for example, something that would work would be a VPN that had a control that said "if someone requests a file over 3GB then keep it on server and give them a much smaller hashed file, then if we see the user upload the hashed file, replace it with the larger one we have"

Does anyone have a similar system that works?

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible*, depending on your level of access to the receiving server.

If you have access to the terminal, (remote) desktop, SSH, or various other methods, you could log in to the receiving server and download the file directly to it.  However, I based on the fact you are asking this, I am going to assume you do not have direct access to the receiving server.  This means you will keep on having to download to your computer, then upload to the other server.

Comment: It's more that - I _could_ have access (ssh ect) to a third party server, but I want to hear about other approaches that might work.